# Pacman saying no update, but pamac saying there are some?

Tags: manjaro, pacman, software-updates

Wanting to try out Arch Linux, I installed Manjaro, and so far find it pretty good.
However, I have a problem, I am used to Debian's `apt update` then `apt upgrade`, and the fact pacman combine both with `pacman -Syu` is awesome.

However, pamac, the GUI for pacman installed by default in XFCE Manjaro, is telling me that there are update to be made:

[image: pacman and pamac side by side]

Is there anything that I just didn't saw in the manual?

Comment: I guess they're out of sync? Have you refreshed the package list in pamac since the `pacman -Syu`?

Comment: @Anko: Yes, but it seems it is pacman that is late, I have Firefox 56 installed, pacman says up to date, but pamac tell me it can upgrade to 57.

Comment: Try `pacman -Syyu` to force a database update. If pamac still claims there are updates after pacman finishes updating from that, then refresh pamac by going back to its main menu and doing another check.

Comment: @Mioriin: Sorry for the long time to answer, I had updated via paman in the meantime, so I had to wait for new package to need update to try your solution. I can now confirm it indeed work, and would be pleased to see this as a answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mioriin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/201836/mioriin) suggested in the comments - `sudo pacman -Syyu` will force a sync for pacman's database.

To make sure pamac shows the right updates:

In pamac (GUI) go to menu and choose "Refresh Databases" which will sync the package databases for pamac.

Now you should see that both will offer the same package updates (if there are any).

Comment: In my case, `sudo pacman -Syyuu` solved the issue